# Making watermark in Kohana 3

Tags: image, image-processing, kohana, watermark

Please help me to fix this problem in Kohana 3 as soon as possible. Kohana is an image module in which it is possible to manipulate images like crop, resize etc. I am trying to make a watermark by this module. Code looks like this:

```
    $image = Image::factory('image-path');
    $image->watermark('watermark-image.png',100,100,80);
    $image->save();
```

but I got the following error:

```
 Argument 1 passed to Kohana_Image::watermark() must be an instance of Image, none given, called in /var/www/virtual/verana.ge/htdocs/application/classes/model/fileupload.php on line 73 and defined
```

can you please tell me how to fix this error and make water mark in Kohana 3.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine this will do the trick:

```
$image = Image::factory('image-path');
$watermark = Image::factory('watermark-image.png');
$image->watermark($watermark,100,100,80);
$image->save();
```

The error states that the watermark method wants an instance of the Image class, not a string.